# Integration Testing Azure Durable Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have an application that uses Azure Durable Functions in which an orchestration is triggered by a `ServiceBusTrigger`. The class in which this happens has an instance of `IDurableClient` injected by DI. When I run the application locally in VS2022, everything works as expected, also when it's deployed to Azure.

I followed the instructions at https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/azure-functions-part-2-unit-and-integration-testing/ba-p/3769764#toc-hId-88794323
that clearly and concisely instruct on how to perform integration tests in the context of Azure Functions. Following this, I was able to successfully write integrations tests for all the `HttpTrigger`-ed functions. These tested functions consume many different services from the DI container (APIs, databases, storage, etc), and it all works as expected.

However, when specifically attempting to perform integration testing of a durable function, it is not behaving as expected. As with the integration tests against the `HttpTrigger`-ed functions,
an instance of the class containing the functions to be tested is obtained through DI. To facilitate testing without having to mock service bus infrastructure, it contains the following methods:

```cs
    [FunctionName(nameof(SendNotificationListener))]
    [Singleton(Mode = SingletonMode.Listener)]
    public async Task SendNotificationListener(
        [ServiceBusTrigger(SEND_NOTIFICATION_QUEUE_NAME, Connection = "SBCon")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage msg
    ) {
        await StartOrchestration(msg.Body);
    }

    public async Task<string> StartOrchestration(
        BinaryData payload
    ) {
        return await _durableClient.StartNewAsync(orchestratorFunctionName: nameof(MainOrchestrator), input: payload.ToString());
    }
```

This allows me to invoke `StartOrchestration()` from the test case and get the returned instance ID. The problem is, the orchestration doesn't start. When invoking through the `ServiceBusTrigger`-ed function, the orchestrator (`MainOrchestrator`) is started, as expected. But when invoking `StartOrchestration()` from the test case (with an appropriate payload that is 100% identical to that obtained from the body of the `ServiceBusReceivedMessage` in `SendNotificationListener()`) the `MainOrchestrator` is not instantiated. When I inspect the task hub tables in table storage, I can see that a new instance is inserted into the Instances table. But the orchestrator itself is not triggered.

Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: I think it has something to do with how the webjobs are configured. When I compare the services in the ServiceCollection in the application's Startup and the testcase's TestStartup, there are way more that relate to durable functions in the Startup. So now I need to figure out how to furnish the services so that it has the same. I've found some extensions, but noithing that seems to make any difference. Anyone have any ideas?